how do we set the relationship tree in sequelize
my question is here :
`// Define Associations
`User.hasMany(Post, { foreignKey: "userId" }); // A User can have many Posts
Post.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId" }); // A Post belongs to a User

Comment.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId" }); // A Comment belongs to a User
Comment.belongsTo(Post, { foreignKey: "postId" }); // A Comment belongs to a Post``

as a user has many posts , and a post has many comments , then why in this code the post has many comments isnt specified ? please explain in a very detaileld explanation cuz i have a project in two days and this confuses me so much .

If you have a foreign key then you link two tables (obviously), right?  What associations you define based on this FK is totally depends on you and what your app needs to get.
Back to your example: if you don't need to get all comments of a certain post then you can simply not to define Post.hasMany(Comment, ... association at all.
The associations you showed can be used to get:

user/users with their posts
post/posts with a linked user
comment/comments with a linked post and/or a linked user

If you want to get post/posts with their comments then you do need to define:
Post.hasMany(Comment, { foreignKey: "postId" }); // Comments of a post

Defining an association you just give a hint to Sequelize how models are linked and it could have nothing with real foreign keys in DB or could reflect only a subset of table relations in DB. Usually you define two associations per one FK: hasMany/belongsTo, hasOne/belongsTo or two belongsToMany but sometimes you just don't need some of them and it could lead to only one association per the FK.
